# Resharper "join declaration and assignment" don't convert to "var"

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

When using Resharper and editing C# code, when I choose to apply a "join declaration and assignment" suggestion, it changes my explicit type declaration to "var".  Example:

If I have:

```
int myNumber;
myNumber = 0;
```

It will refactor it to:

```
var myNumber = 0;
```

I do not like this.  I prefer to use explicit type names in my declarations unless I'm using "new" to call the constructor in the same line.

Is there a way to tell Resharper to keep my explicit type declaration when joining declaration and assignment instead of converting it to "var", so that the refactored code comes out as:

```
int myNumber = 0;
```

Comment: David, the answer that you pointed to in the page does not answer my question.  If I'm not mistaken, that area in the settings only controls what recommendations are made, not how it behaves when applying a change.  I tried changing it anyway, and it did not change the behavior.

Comment: @JoeMjr2: What version of ReSharper are you using?

Comment: @Malice: JetBrains ReSharper 9.0 Update 1 Build 9.0.20141219.130142 on 2014-12-19 13:12:31Z

Comment: As I see, to get "int" here instead of "var", you need to select "Use explicit type" in ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Code Style | var usage in declaration.

Comment: @Alexander, that worked perfectly!  If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get "int" here instead of "var", you need to select `"Use explicit type"` in `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Code Style | var usage in declaration`.

Comment: That option has an additional setting 'Use var when evident' that appears to be closer to what the op desires, which is to use explicit types and use var only when the assigning expression already states the type explicitly (as is the case for a new expression).